# Device physical back button does not work when locate any location on google map fragment

Tags: android, maps

**What i did:**  I had added a map fragment on my screen to locate the entered location from edittext box to the map. Before locating the location, if i press back button, it works smooth. But after locating the location on google map fragment, onBackPressed does not work.

**What i want:** i want my device physical back button to work as default.

I am locating the place on map fragments on keyboard enter press button.
Any solution/idea will be highly appreciated.

Thanks !

**EDIT:: ** this is what i had done:

```
myEditTextBox.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
// My code here...
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and this is my onBackPressed() :

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(mtIntent to call another activity);
}
```

Comment: Are you Overriding *onBackPressed()* method in your activity?

Comment: Show what have you done!!

Comment: onKey() method, try to return True only inside the IF bloc otherwise return False. You should return true if you handled the event but if you want the event to be handled by the next receiver, return false.

Comment: @Rami ... Yo man.. working now.. thanks for the help :-)

Comment: You are welcome! i'll add my comment as an answer, if someone else have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onKey()** method, return `true` only inside the **IF** bloc otherwise return `false`.

You should return `true` if you handled the event but if you want the event to be handled by the next receiver, return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following when overriding onBackPressed():

`@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),youActivityHere.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}`